# How to create a subscribtion on SSRS with a dynamic parameter start and end date for a report running off three datasets

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have created a report pulling data from four different datasets with all containing a parameter of startDate and EndDates. All datasets include the same table where this parameter is found. I want to create a subscription email for users to receive on a weekly basis (-7 days from run date).

Comment: You can create the regular/data-driven subscription. As per your requirement, you can choose the regular one, as data-driven subscription is not required for this report. I am adding a link for both, you can take a look at that

https://jackworthen.com/2016/05/06/creating-a-data-driven-subscription-in-sql-server-reporting-services/

https://www.tutorialgateway.org/report-subscription-in-ssrs/

Answer (score 0):

You can setup an Email Subscription in SSRS in Report Delivery Options section. Please watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sO0Y_IxdE8w) for more details.

If you don't have an E-mail Delivery Extension configured on your Reporting Services yet then please read the detailed guidelines [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/e-mail-settings-reporting-services-native-mode-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 0):

When creating a report, I create parameters for the dates and set the **default values** for the desired range on a regular basis.

If you want the previous weeks worth of data on a given day, you could use

```
=TODAY.AddDays(-7)
```

for the Start Date default value and

```
=TODAY.AddDays(-1)
```

for the End Date default value. On 6/4 this gives 5/28 for the Start date and 6/3 for the End Date.

With these default values, your report will always run for the previous week but can also be run for other dates when necessary.